# How to send xml/application format in bottle?

Tags: bottle

If some one come to my url suppose /get it should give back a xml/application format in response in bottle framework. How can i do this? i am using elementree as xml generator.

Comment: What is bottle, and what does it have to do with Django?

Comment: there's no reason to vote it down, I think its a legitimate question, altough a bit overeagerly tagged.....

Comment: Did you mean a mime-type of application/xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look on the [official page](http://bottle.paws.de/) for the cookie example and do it like this:

```
@route('/xml')
def xml():
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'xml/application'
    ....(create the xml here)......
    return xml_content_whatever
```

Comment: Or `response.content_type = 'xml/application'`