# python bottle css template

Tags: python, bottle

I'm trying to enable dynamic styling to a project I'm working on, so that the user can style according to his/her own house colors.

I wanted to do something like

```
from bottle import route, run, template,

@route('/')
def home():
  return template("sandbox")


@route('/mystyle.css')
def giveCss():
  print("Giving css")
  return template("sandbox_css")
```

sandbox.tpl:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>
<table >
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

sandbox_css.tpl

```
table, th, td {
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

however, the css isn't rendered in this simple case.
In the future I would've liked to be able to do this:

sandbox_css.tpl

```
table, th, td {
   border: 1px solid {{tableBorderColor}};
}
```

sandbox.py

```
@route('/mystyle.css')
def giveCss():
  print("Giving css")
  return template("sandbox_css", tableBorderColor="black")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found it just by chance, because of some output chrome gave:

> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type
>   text/html

when googling on changing the MIME-type, I came upon this:
[How to send xml/application format in bottle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490744/how-to-send-xml-application-format-in-bottle)

which led me to the solution of doing this:

```
@route('/mystyle.css')
def giveCss():
  print("Giving css")
  response.content_type = 'text/css'
  return template("sandbox_css", borderColor="red")
```

In short, I change the response content type to 'text/css'

Comment: Why don't you use static_file to return a CSS?

Comment: because I wanted to dynamically change the CSS based on what you can configure in a webpage/stored in a DB